# Validity of substituting identically distributed r.v. in expectation

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, brownian-motion

The question is motivated by increments of a standard brownian motion. Assuming $s<t$, I now $B_t-B_s$ is identically distributed from $B_{t+h}-B_{s+h}$. If I want to prove (in the trivial case, that $B_t$ is brownian motion) that $B_t-B_s$ is normally distributed, I use the characteristic function $E[e^{i \theta (B_t-B_s)}]$ and I must replace it, giving $E[e^{i \theta (B_{t-s}-B_0)}]=E[e^{i \theta(t-s)^{1/2}B_1}]$. At the end my question is if this is valid. I replaced $B_t-B_s$ for $B_{t-s}-B_0$ and then replaced it by $\sqrt{t-s}B_1$ all justified in assuming that if I replace a rv with another which is identically distributed, I would know E(f(X))=E(f(Y)).

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: Even for general $X\overset{d}{=}Y $ and $f$?

Comment: Yes, this is due to the change of variables theorem

Comment: I am sorry. I know the theorem, but don't see obvious why it applies here. X and Y could also be disrete. Could you expand?

Comment: It asserts $$E f(X) = \int f(x)\,\mu(dx),\quad \mu(B) = P(X\in B)$$, i.e. the expectation of a random variable depends only on its distribution $\mu$, and not the underlying probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ on which it is defined

Comment: So it would also be a double implication? If $E(f(X))=E(f(Y))$ then X equals Y in distribution?

Comment: if you forgot to add the quantifier for all bounded continuous $f$, then yes. Otherwise, no.